# Firestore how to combine a realtime check with a promise

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

```js
listenToCreationInAnotherCollection(rightId, promise) {
    return dataBase.connect()
      .collection('anotherCollection')
      .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
          snapshot.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
              if (change.type === "added" && change.doc.id === rightId) {
                  promise.resolve()
              }
          });
      }, error => {
        promise.reject()
      })
  }
```

I'm trying to achieve something like this:

```js
var myPromise = new Promise();
const unsubscribe = subscriptionsService.listenToCreationInAnotherCollection("rightDocumentId", myPromise)
// myAsyncOperation() creates an object in a collection, which also triggers 
// (thanks to a trigger in another cloud function) a document creation 
// in "anotherCollection"
await myAsyncOperation()
await myPromise
unsubscribe()
```

Basically what I want to do is to launch the unsubscribe function (to close the connection) when the document creation in anotherCollection has been a success. This doesn't work because the promise is not well defined. How could I achieve this?

Should `listenToCreationInAnotherCollection` directly return a promise ? How could I call `unsubscribe()` then ?

I have this error `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Promise resolver undefined is not a function` for the promise declaration

Comment: "This doesn't work because the promise is not well defined" What do you mean by that? Is there an error?

Comment: Yes `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Promise resolver undefined is not a function` but I don't really know how to define the promise function to make it work in this special case

Comment: Can you add that error *and the stack trace showing where it comes from{* to the question?

Comment: Thanks I added it, the full stacktrace is useless because I simplified the problem for this question to the essentials. I know how to create "common" promises but here I need a way to call a resolve function "outside" of the promise which is the part that makes me struggle. If I could not use a promise that would be even better but it seems that you can't call `unsubscribe()` inside `docChanges().forEach((change))`